# How to set current selected date in AlertDialog CustomView from DatePicker in AlertDialog CustomView

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a `AlertDialog` that uses a **custom view**. The View includes a **textview** and a **DatePicker**. I want to set the current date from the datepicker in the textview.

Here is a screenshot of the AlertDialog 
[image]

My `AlertDialog` is as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        titleText.setText("Add Book and Renew Date");
        titleText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        titleText.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        titleText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        alert.setCustomTitle(titleText)
                .setView(R.layout.alertdialog_content)
                .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCELLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        Log.d("BeforShow", "HEREEEE");
        alertDialog.show();
```

I want to set the Current set date from the DatePicker int the **current set date** textview so that the user can see the date he/she has picked.

Comment: Have you tried using `OnDateSetListener()`?

Comment: I am new to Android Development. I dont know where in AlertDialog I can use the OnDateSetListener() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you need to change the "**current set date**" instead of "**current set time**" as asked in your question. Anyway...

You have the instance for the date picker in you custom dialog. Use the `onDateChangedListener` and you can change the text view as this method.This returns the day,date and month values when the date is changed. This method is called when a change in the date occurs from your date picker.

Detailed reference :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html

God Speed !!

Answer (score 3):

DatePicker 101 here, sorry for the pun

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //here you go
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ]
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```